# Ubuntu without setuid

Tags: kernel, security

Linux kernel supports setuid, setgid permission for executable binaries.

Is it possible to build a kernel without these capabilities?

Without these, administrators are the only users that can tamper the system.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, `setuid` and `setgid` programs are not installed. I would have to install `setuid` with `sudo apt install super`. So for me at least it's not built into the kernel. Perhaps you can give an example of how you are using `setuid` and `setgid` to show they are in the kernel?

Comment: My bad. If one installs Ubuntu to a FAT partition, then all these things are automatically gone. So, we are standing in the thin line between kernel and user applications. Should be PAM, NSS or ACL components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably possible to remove this feature from the kernel, and it's also possible to mount filesystems without suid, using the `nosuid` option. This strikes me as simpler, and would achieve the same thing.

But it breaks a **lot** of features. This is a list of commands in `/usr/` and `/bin/ that is setuid on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ find /usr /bin -perm -4000 
/usr/bin/pkexec
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/arping
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap
/usr/lib/eject/dmcrypt-get-device
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
/usr/lib/s-nail/s-nail-privsep
/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
/usr/sbin/pppd
/bin/ping
/bin/mount
/bin/umount
/bin/su
/bin/fusermount
```

Users will not be able to change their own passwords anymore. They will not be able to mount USB devices. They will not be able to elevate privileges. They will not be able to ping remove hosts. And probably more unintended consequenses.

In short, you're probably barking up the wrong three if your goal is to secure your system. A better approach is probably to look into AppArmomur or SELinux, which attempts to enforce user permissions in a more rigorous manner than the standard Linux kernel. It comes at a cost: increased complexity.

If you do this to a vanilla Ubuntu system, you will probably see all kinds of *interesting* behaviour.

Comment: To have military-grade security, applications are all installed using external disks on rebooting into single-user mode, much different from Internet-connected `apt`-style.

Comment: Is there a specific security case you want to protect against, or a specific problem you seek to solve? What do you gain from rebooting into single user mode to install software?

Comment: Anecdote (and unrelated to Ubuntu): @vidarlo I know you also use SUSE. That OS has a mechanism to revoke permissions from certain commands: `chkstat`. It comes with some predefined configuration files below `/etc`, e.g. `permissions.easy` or `permissions.paranoid`. When applied, they change the `rwx` settings and sometimes also remove the `s` bits from certain commands. The effect is as you say: no more `passwd`, no more `ping`, no more `crontab`, etc. for regular users.

Comment: @PerlDuck Quite true, and Suse also has an (excellent) GUI for AppArmour through YaST. And the [security module of YaST](https://i.imgur.com/WDeMfT5.png) is rather good as well. But this is rather tangential to AU :)